# Найти макс значение двумерного массива

Tags: java, матрицы

Надо найти макс значение двумерного массива.
Вот сама функция:

```
int max = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
    max = matrix[i][0];

    for(int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++){
        if(max < matrix[i][j]){
            max = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}

return max;
```

Но если поставить значение матрицы = `{{100, 200, 300}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}};`
Он выдаёт 8, хотя должно 300. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Строкой `max = matrix[i][0];` после первого цикла Вы указываете программе искать максимальное значение отдельно **на каждой итерации**, а не во всей матрице. Следовательно, каждое последующее вычисление переопределяет предыдущее. Выходит, что сохраняется максимум из последней строки `{6, 7, 8}`.

Если Вы хотите искать максимум во всей матрице, то эта строка Вам не нужна:

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++){
        if(max < matrix[i][j]){
            max = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}

return max;
```

Comment: Если в матрице могут быть отрицательные числа (а в условии не сказано, что их там быть не может), то `int max = 0;` не годится. Надо `int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;` или `int max = matrix[0][0]`, но во втором случае надо предусмотреть возможность нулевого размера матрицы или ее первой (в смысле нулевой) строки

Comment: @m.vokhm, согласен, исправил.